# Parsing JSON string with jQuery.parseJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, this should be simple in my mind... I have a valid JSON string being returned through an Ajax post:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Thank you! We value your feedback."}
```

And I'm simply trying to alert my "message" value onto my resulting post return:

```
success: function (result) {
   alert(result);
   var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
   alert(obj.message);
  },
error: function (req, status, error) {
   alert("Sorry! We could not receive your feedback at this time.");
  }
```

My "obj" attributes somehow aren't being recognized..... I've validated the JSON string to make sure it was valid, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to parse your JSON. Set the `dataType` attribute to `json` and jQuery will parse it for you. Then, `result` is essentially your JSON and you can do `alert(data.message);`.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  ...
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
     alert(data.message);
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening in this case is that jQuery is already treating your result as a JSON object. If your server returns the data with a MIME type of `application/json`, jQuery will detect that you're returning JSON and set the result to a javascript object rather than a string.